# AS3 preloader with external swc files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, preloader, swc

I have a project created from many external swc libraries that are included at compile-time.

Normally creating a preloader involves unchecking "export in frame 1" on all classes, then having them on the 2nd frame so Flash can still access them.

With the swc's however, all the classes are in separate swc file libraries. When I uncheck "export in frame 1", I can't access them from the main FLA file, and so flash just can't find them and gives errors saying those classes don't exist. How can I make them loaded properly with the preloader (instead of being loaded all at once before preloader displays), even though they are in other files?

Long story short, how can I properly make a preloader when I'm using multiple swc files at compile-time?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just make a separate swf for a preloader and load your main content through a `Loader`? That way you don't have to rely on Flash CS so much.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible as the game needs to be a single file for distribution.

There must be a way to use an internal preloader when dealing with multiple swc's.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand what swcs are. Even though they are at development time external files, they are very much part of your compiled app when you publish. If you include a swc that is 50M then your app will end up being 50M bigger and your preloader will have to deal with it. No workarounds.

Comment: You misunderstand my question. the swc files are part of the game, but they can not be preloaded. Instead the entire swf file is loaded with a blank screen before the preloader even shows. Normally to make it work, all content needs to be on frame 2, which isn't possible when the content is in other swf files and not the main fla.

Comment: I understand just fine and like I said it's not possible.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying if I include a 50mb swc, then the SWF will have to load all 50mb before displaying the preloader, since preloaders can not properly load included swc content after the loader is displayed?

(I thought you were just telling me that +50mb swc = +50mb swf)

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying. I don't think a workaround is possible due to the way swcs are treated at compile time. If they do include graphics/sounds, you should look into bringing them in as swf or even load them externally by themselves.